# Display Parent-Children in single line in Crystal Reports

Tags: database, crystal-reports, crosstab, crystal-reports-2010

Is the following possible with Crystal Reports?

Table A

```
ID Boo  Far
1  Test 15
2  Tast 24
```

Table B

```
Foo Bar ParentID
A   1   1
B   2   1
C   3   1
A   17  2
c   18  2
```

And I want my report to look like

```
ID Boo  Far A  B  C 
1  Test 15  1  2  3
2  Tast 24  17    18
```

Withou using a cross table? Because with a crosstable, I get the headers A,B,C but cannot display headers for ID, Boo and Far. Also, I can row-summerize A,B and C per record but I cannot create a column-sum of all B's for all records.

I already tried creating a nice group-by, but this gives me results like :

```
ID Boo  Far 
1  Test 15  
            Bar
            1
            2
            3
```

Which seems normal of course. But I (or, the customer...) doesn't want that.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a group on {Table A.ID}
Add Table A fields to group-header section; suppress group-footer section

Create three formula:

```
// {@a}
If {Table B.Foo}='A' Then {Table B.Bar}
Else 0

// {@b}
If {Table B.Foo}='B' Then {Table B.Bar}
Else 0

// {@c}
If {Table B.Foo}='C' Then {Table B.Bar}
Else 0
```

Add to Details section.  Hide details section

Insert a summary field on each of these formula.  Move to group-header section; align with column headers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use variables to keep track of the values for A, B, C per entry in Table A.

1. Keep the grouping you've already set up for {TableA.ID}. Move all the items you want to display into the group footer.
2. In the (now empty) group header, initialize/redim an array of size 3.
3. In the (now empty) details section, conditionally update the array, such that index 1 contains the value for 'A', 2 for 'B', etc. Like this:

   ```
   whileprintingrecords;
   numbervar array myArray;
   select {TableB.Foo}
    case 'A' : myArray[1]:={tableB.Bar}
    case 'B' : myArray[2]:={tableB.Bar}
    case 'C' : myArray[3]:={tableB.Bar}
    default : 0 //handle error case
   ```
4. Suppress both the group header and details section so they don't display on your report.
5. Now, in the group footer you should have access to all of the correspondent values of tableB for A, B, C for each parent record in tableA.

Note: All your formulas will need to use `whileprintingrecords;` to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the cross-tab object, but I'm not sure what your data really looks like.

To address:

> cannot display headers for ID, Boo and Far.

you can combine them into a new column to display as the rowheader.  They won't show as individual columns like A, B, and C, just one for the tuple.

to address:

> I cannot create a column-sum of all B's for all records.

I introduce a new row, sorted last, with all the sums for each group in the datasource.